# How to use nested and or query in Mongoid 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

In former version of Mongoid I would write:

```
Clothes.where("$or" => [{"$and" => [{_type: "Shoes"}, {is_secondhand: false}]}, 
                        {"$and"=> [{_type: "Shirts"}, {is_secondhand: true}]}])
```

How should I write that in Mongoid 3.0.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need those *ands*.

Try this:

```
Clothes.or({_type: "Shoes", is_secondhand: false},
           {_type: "Shirts", is_secondhand: true})
```

A lot has changed in Mongoid 3 and most of the querying selectors were moved to Origin. Have a look at the [Origin documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html).